# Issue with tcl array index and passing array in function

Tags: tcl

I have two questions:

In one of my tcl functions an array is declared and initialized as follows:

```
 foreach port $StcPorts {
  set dutport [lindex $DutPortsTmp $i]

  set STCPort($dutport) [list 0 [lindex [lindex $cardlist $port] 0] [lindex [lindex $cardlist $port] 1]]
}
```

This is pretty confusing to me since I am new to tcl. Please help me to understand the above code on STCPort creation.

Question 2:

In the same file, STCPort is being used like this:

```
 foreach dutport $DutPortsTmp {
    set slot [lindex $STCPort($dutport) 1]
    set port [lindex $STCPort($dutport) 2]
    set hPort [stc::create port -under $hProject -location //$stcipaddress/$slot/$port -useDefaultHost False ]
    lappend STCPort($dutport) $hPort
 }
```

I have sourced this file and my requirement is to get the hPort value in another function residing in another file and work on it. Below is the function d_stc:

```
proc d_stc {args} {
   global DutPorts STCPort 

   upvar 1 $STCPort _STCPort

   #I am trying to get hPort by array index below:
   foreach DutPort $DutPorts {
    set card [lindex $_STCPort($DutPort) 1]
    set port [lindex $_STCport($DutPort) 2]
    set hport [lindex $_STCPort($DutPort) 3]

   }
```

And, I am getting the following error:

```
 can't read "STCPort": variable is array
 while executing
"upvar 1 $STCPort _STCPort"
 (procedure "d_stc" line 3)
```

I have used global to access the array in this function. But, where I am going wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach port $StcPorts {
    set dutport [lindex $DutPortsTmp $i]

    set STCPort($dutport) [list 0 [lindex [lindex $cardlist $port] 0] [lindex [lindex $cardlist $port] 1]]
}
```

This snippet goes through the elements of the list `StcPorts`, which seem to be integers representing some kind of port numbers. For every port number, an array index (stored as `dutport`) is generated by taking the *ith* element from the list `DutPortsTmp`. The value of `i` is unexplained by this snippet. Also for everly port number, an array value in the array `STCPort` is created, with the index created above, and a value constructed like this:

- Get the element in the list `cardlist` that corresponds to the integer index `port` (call that C)
- Form a list from the three items 0, the first subitem in *C*, and the second subitem in *C*.

.

```
foreach dutport $DutPortsTmp {
    set slot [lindex $STCPort($dutport) 1]
    set port [lindex $STCPort($dutport) 2]
    set hPort [stc::create port -under $hProject -location //$stcipaddress/$slot/$port -useDefaultHost False ]
    lappend STCPort($dutport) $hPort
}
```

The list `DutPortsTmp`, which was used to create array indexes, reappears. We work with every item in the list, with the list item/array index again being named `dutport`. For every iteration, we look at the corresponding array item, setting `slot` to the second item of the array item's value (the first item in *C*, above) and `port` to the third item of the array item's value (the second item in *C*). The result of an invocation of `stc::create port` is assigned to the variable `hPort`, and the value of the array item is extended with a new list item, the value in `hPort`.

```
proc d_stc {args} {
   global DutPorts STCPort 

   upvar 1 $STCPort _STCPort

   #I am trying to get hPort by array index below:
   foreach DutPort $DutPorts {
    set card [lindex $_STCPort($DutPort) 1]
    set port [lindex $_STCport($DutPort) 2]
    set hport [lindex $_STCPort($DutPort) 3]

}
```

This should probably be:

```
proc d_stc {args} {
   global DutPorts STCPort 

   foreach DutPort $DutPorts {
     set hport [lindex $STCPort($DutPort) 3]
   }
}
```

The corrected snippet again goes through the array indexes for `STCPort`, but this time `DutPorts` is used instead of `DutPortsTmp` to get the array indexes. The `hport` variable gets the value of the fourth item in each of the array items.

But: the value in `hport` is never used or returned anywhere, and the value is overwritten by a new value from each new item looked at.

```
upvar 1 $STCPort _STCPort
```

does not work since there is no string value in `STCPort`. If the procedure is called from the global level, this would work:

```
upvar 1 STCPort _STCPort
```

(See the difference? Not the value of `STCPort`, but the string `"STCPort"` itself.) You don't need this: the invocation of `global DutPorts STCPort` already makes the array `STCPort` visible inside the procedure.